# DataTable no es una función

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, tengo una vista en la cual necesito un script. La vista consiste en que tengo una BD con profesores y en esta les permito modificar su contraseña, ademas de ver su lista de alumnos.
Este es el código:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('jumbotron')
    @include('partials.jumbotron', ['title' => 'Configurar tu perfil', 'icon' => 'user-circle'])
@endsection

@push('styles')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
@endpush

@section('content')
    <div class="pl-5 pr-5">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        {{ __("Actualiza tus datos") }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('profile.update') }}" novalidate>
                            @csrf
                            @method('PUT')

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">
                                    {{ __("Correo electrónico") }}
                                </label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input
                                            id="email"
                                            type="email"
                                            readonly
                                            class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"
                                            name="email"
                                            value="{{ old('email') ?: $user->email }}"
                                            required
                                            autofocus
                                    />

                                    @if($errors->has('email'))
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label
                                        for="password"
                                        class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right"
                                >
                                    {{ __("Contraseña") }}
                                </label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input
                                            id="password"
                                            type="password"
                                            class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"
                                            name="password"
                                            required
                                    />

                                    @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label
                                        for="password-confirm"
                                        class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right"
                                >
                                    {{ __("Confirma la contraseña") }}
                                </label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input
                                            id="password-confirm"
                                            type="password"
                                            class="form-control"
                                            name="password_confirmation"
                                            required
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                                <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        {{ __("Actualizar datos") }}
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>

                @if( ! $user->teacher)
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            {{ __("Convertirme en profesor de la plataforma") }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <form action="{{ route('solicitude.teacher') }}" method="POST">
                                @csrf
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block">
                                    <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i> {{ __("Solicitar") }}
                                </button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @else
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            {{ __("Administrar los cursos que imparto") }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <a href="{{ route('teacher.courses') }}" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">
                                <i class="fa fa-leanpub"></i> {{ __("Administrar ahora") }}
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            {{ __("Mis estudiantes") }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <table
                                    class="table table-striped table-bordered nowrap"
                                    cellspacing="0"
                                    id="students-table"
                            >
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>{{ __("ID") }}</th>
                                    <th>{{ __("Nombre") }}</th>
                                    <th>{{ __("Email") }}</th>
                                    <th>{{ __("Cursos") }}</th>
                                    <th>{{ __("Acciones") }}</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endif

                @if($user->socialAccount)
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            {{ __("Acceso con Socialite") }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-block">
                                {{ __("Registrado con") }}: <i class="fa fa-{{ $user->socialAccount->provider }}"></i>
                                {{ $user->socialAccount->provider }}
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @include('partials.modal')
@endsection

@push('scripts')
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        let dt;
        let modal = jQuery("#appModal");
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            dt = jQuery("#students-table").DataTable({

            })
        })
    </script>
@endpush
```

Durante esta se usa una vista llamada modal.blade.php:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="appModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="appModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="appModalLabel"></h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">{{ __("Cerrar") }}</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="modalAction"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Deberia verse del siguiente modo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero se acaba viendo más bien así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen se muestra que hay un error por el cual no se reconoce el metodo "jQuery("#students-table").DataTable".
¿Que estare haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1):

**Te muestra ese error por que solo estas cargando a datatables pero en ningún momento invocas a jquery, sigue las indicaciones que te doy, puedes incluir esto al final por ejemplo de tu archivo app.blade.php por que segun noto es el que usas como plantilla base**

Necesitas colocar justo antes de que cierre la etiqueta body, el llamado a tus librerias, en este orden

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

> Siempre JQuery va primero pues datatables depende en su core de las
>   funcionalidades de el antes mencionado

Comment: excelente muchas gracias por tu aporte

Comment: @alejandro avisame si te funciona

Comment: ¿Donde iria concretamente? No hay aqui una etiqueta body. He probado a ponerlo en varios sitios del @push('script'), pero sigue igual.

Comment: @MiguelAlparez checa mi comentario en la edición

Comment: @MiguelAlparez agrega el cpodigo de tu archivo app para indicarte donde deberia ir

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he arreglado.
Al final resulta que el error estuvo en un fichero llamado app.blade.php
Es decir, antes lo tenia así:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Slabo+27px" rel="stylesheet">

    @stack('styles')

</head>
<body>
    @include('partials.navigation')
    @yield('jumbotron')
    <div id="app">
        <main class="py-4">
            @if(session('message'))
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <div class="alert alert-{{session('message')[0]}}">
                            <h4 class="alert-heading">{{__("Mensaje informativo")}}</h4>
                            <p>{{session('message')[1]}}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endif
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>

    @include('partials.footer')

    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

    @stack('scripts')
</body>
</html>
```

Ahora lo tengo así:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Slabo+27px" rel="stylesheet">

    @stack('styles')

</head>
<body>
@include('partials.navigation')

@yield('jumbotron')

<div id="app">
    <main class="py-4">
        @if(session('message'))
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="alert alert-{{ session('message')[0] }}">
                        <h4 class="alert-heading">{{ __("Mensaje informativo") }}</h4>
                        <p>{{ session('message')[1] }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endif
        @yield('content')
    </main>
</div>

@include('partials.footer')

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

@stack('scripts')

</body>
</html>
```

Resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]